# Get the details from a MySQL table without sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization

I am using a `MySQL` query to fetch data from 2 tables. Here I have a status `Transfer Out` in **table2**. I do need to fetch all the details with status `Transfer Out` and at the same time, there should not be any details with `Transfer In` status which is added after the `Transfer Out`. **So that I should not get the details which are `Transfer back In` after a `Transfer Out`**.

Right now I am using `subquery` for the same. But when the data count gets higher, it is causing timeout issues. Is there a better way to rewrite the query and get the same result?

**My query sample is**

```
SELECT  sq.etid
    FROM (
        SELECT  og.etid, pt.timestamp
            FROM  og_membership og
            INNER JOIN  table1 n ON(n.nid=og.etid)
            INNER JOIN  table2 pt ON(og.etid=pt.animal_nid)
            WHERE  og.entity_type='node'
              AND  pt.partner_gid = :gid
              AND  pt.shelter_gid = :our_gid
              AND  pt.type = 'Transfer Out'
              AND  (
                SELECT  count(id)
                    FROM  table2
                    WHERE  timestamp > pt.timestamp
                      AND  type = 'Transfer In'
                      AND  partner_gid = :gid
                      AND  shelter_gid = :our_gid
                   ) = 0
       ) AS sq
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as saying where last transaction is 'transfer out' or can there be a transaction other than transfer in which can happen after transfer out?

Comment: "from 2 tables" -- Looks like 3 tables!

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do this with a group by for example

```
select something
from somehwere
group by something having isnull(max(out_date),0) > isnull(max(indate) ,0)
```

For example

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOANS;

CREATE TABLE LOANS (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ISBN INT,DIRECTION VARCHAR(3), DT DATETIME);

INSERT INTO LOANS(ISBN,DIRECTION,DT) VALUES
(1,'OUT','2017-10-01 09:00:00'),
(2,'OUT','2017-10-02 10:00:00'),
(2,'IN', '2017-10-02 10:10:00'),
(3,'REC','2017-10-02 10:00:00'),
(4,'REC','2017-10-02 10:00:00'),
(4,'OUT','2017-10-03 10:00:00'),
(4,'IN', '2017-10-04 10:00:00'),
(4,'OUT','2017-10-05 10:00:00')
;

SELECT ISBN
FROM   LOANS
WHERE  DIRECTION IN('OUT','IN') 
GROUP BY ISBN HAVING        
         MAX(CASE WHEN DIRECTION = 'OUT' THEN DT ELSE 0 END)  >
         MAX(CASE WHEN DIRECTION = 'IN'  THEN DT ELSE 0 END) ;
```

result

```
+------+
| ISBN |
+------+
|    1 |
|    4 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In case of a tie on DT you could substitute id.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But the thing is, there is no such fields like out_date and indate. Both have a single timestamp column and new row will be added if an intake/outcome made

Comment: The principle doesn't change please see example added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
( SELECT COUNT(id) FROM ... ) = 0
```

to

```
EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ... )
```

Get rid of the outermost query and the first `pt.timestamp`.  (Or is there some obscure reason for `pt.timestamp`?)

`table2` needs `INDEX(type, partner_gid, shelter_gid, timestamp)`.  `timestamp` must be last, but the others can be in any order.

`table2` needs `INDEX(type, partner_gid, shelter_gid, animal_nid)`; the columns can be in any order.  (This index *cannot* be combined with the previous one.)

`og_membership` needs `INDEX(etid, entity_type)` (in either order).

Why do you have `INNER JOIN  table1 n ON(n.nid=og.etid)` in the query?  `table1` does not seem to be used at all -- except maybe for verifying the existence of a row.  Remove it if possible.

After making changes, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 2 (or 3??) tables.